# Override Chrome Storage API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I would like to override `chrome.storage.local.set` in order to log the value of a storage key when the Chrome Storage API is called:

```
var storage_local_set = chrome.storage.local.set;
chrome.storage.local.set = function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
    storage_local_set(key);    
}
```

But I get `Illegal invocation: Function must be called on an object of type StorageArea` when `storage_local_set(key)` gets called. How can I store the data after logging the key?

For `chrome.storage.sync.set` this is what I tried based on the solution given:

```
const api = chrome.storage.sync;
const { set } = api; 
api.set = function (data, callback) {
  console.log(data);
  set.apply(api, arguments);  
};
```

But this is not hooking the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .call() or .apply() to provide `this` object:

```js
storage_local_set.apply(this, arguments);
```

The parameters in your override don't match the documentation though. If you want to match the documentation then do it like this:

```js
const api = chrome.storage.local;
const { set } = api; 
api.set = function (data, callback) {
  console.log(data);
  set.apply(api, arguments);    
};
```

And if you want to change the signature to separate key and value:

```js
const api = chrome.storage.local;
const { set } = api; 
api.set = (key, value, callback) => {
  console.log(key, value);
  set.call(api, {[key]: value}, callback);    
};
```

Comment: tnx. I wanted to do the same thing with ```chrome.storage.sync``` as well but it's not getting hooked?

Comment: Since I don't see what you did, I can't help.

Comment: You can't have two variables with identical names (`set` and `api`) in the same scope so you need to rename the second ones.

Comment: I did and I'm still not able to hook the API (nothing gets set when ```chrome.storage.sync.set``` gets called

Comment: Well then there's something else wrong which is not related to this code. Or you renamed them incorrectly :-) BTW you can force a new block scope by surrounding the block with `{` and `}`.